# 'get_history' api call is not working for nse index but working for stocks

Tags: python, nsepy

below is working for index as well

```
get_history(symbol="NIFTY",start=date(2015,1,1),end=date(2017,11,11),index=True,futures=True, expiry_date=date(2015,1,29))`
```

did not work, it return `None` after long time:

```
get_history(symbol="NIFTY",start=date(2017,1,1),end=date(2017,11,11),index=True futures=True, expiry_date=date(2017,11,30))
```

Please help me to resolve earliest.

Comment: It is working for me with latest nsepy, are you still getting None?

Comment: Thanks for reply ! not working for me. yes stil getting None. do you want me to try in python3?